# What does importing backend exactly mean?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have seen some codes use lines such as -

```
import keras.backend as K

sess = K.get_session()
```

What does importing backend mean exactly? What does it do, and when do we do it and how does it help?

What exactly is the role that sess and K are playing here?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Check [this](https://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.2.0/backend/) out

Answer (score 2):

`keras` supports multiple [backends](https://keras.io/backend/) (TensorFlow, Theano, CNTK as of today), TensorFlow being the default and so `K` is an abstraction layer on top of the library that you've configured. Its simply the entry point

Comment: So what do you mean by abstraction layer? K is just a dummy expression and invokes tensorflow since its default? Something like that? And also, what do you mean by entry point?